# Error setValue:forUndefinedKey Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

**[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image.**

This is the error code if you have any info or help that would be great

Comment: Post some code where you get this error.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you change the name of an IBOutlet property or remove an IBOutlet property for which a nib (Interface Builder) file still has a reference.  Look for a nib related to the screen where you are experiencing the error, and look for an outdated connection in the Connections inspector that references a property that either changed names or was since deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This is also happen when you set `@property` to any IBOutlet object and forgot to `@synthesized` it.
Make sure the object for which you have set the `@property` in `ViewController.h` file should be `@synthesized` in `ViewController.m` file.

So reason of this error is **IBOutlet object is not set correctly with in XIB and you're using this object any where in your code**.

Comment: from Xcode 4.4 The compiler automatically calls `@synthesize` by default for unimplemented `@properties`.

Comment: Okay !! because I'm still using **XCode Version 4.2.1** so I dont know about 4.4 ... but this happen in this xcode.